# Kotlin - Get Maximum value in ArrayList of Ints

Tags: kotlin

I have this `ArrayList`

```
var amplititudes: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
amplititudes.add(1)
amplititudes.add(2)
amplititudes.add(3)
amplititudes.add(4)
amplititudes.add(3)
amplititudes.add(2)
amplititudes.add(1)
```

I want to get the maximum value i.e 4. What will be the easiest way to find the max element? I know about the `max()` method , but it will forces me to use `?` with the return value since it could be `null`. Is there any solution which is better than this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use built-in functionality with `maxOrNull` ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-or-null.html)):

```
val amplitudes = listOf(1,2,3,4,3,2,1)
val max = amplitudes.maxOrNull() ?: 0
```

Answer (score 15):

`max()` becomes deprecated starting from Kotlin 1.4, please use `maxOrNull()`

```
val list = listOf(10, 2, 33)
val max: Int = list.maxOrNull() ?: 0
```

Comment: plus 1, but please provide an example (as in the other answers) to make your answer complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`max()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max.html), if you want to use the default comparison (as in your case with `int`s), or [`maxBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html), if you want to use a custom `selector` (i.e., algorithm) to compare values.

Note that both return `int?` (in your case), since the collection might be empty (i.e., no maximum value is present)

Answer (score 3):

`max()` deprecated in Kotlin 1.4.
But it was reintroduced in 1.7 . [More details here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew17.html#min-and-max-collection-functions-return-as-non-nullable)

Both `max()` and `maxOrNull()` can be used.
The difference is,

`max()` returns non null values.If the collection is empty it will throw NoSuchElementException.

`maxOrNull()` returns a nullable value, so if element not present in collection it would return null.

If you are sure that collection will not be empty or you have handled exception, you can use `max()`.Otherwise it is recommended is to use `maxOrNull()` and have default value if it returns null.

```
val amplitudes = listOf(10,8,20,15,30,90)

//Here it returns non-null int
val max:Int = amplitudes.max()
println(max) //90

//Here it returns nullable int
val max :Int? = amplitudes.maxOrNull()
println(max) //90

//Here we can make it as non-nullable type using elvis operator.
val max1 :Int = amplitudes.maxOrNull()?:0
println(max) //90


val amplitudes1 = listOf<Int>()
val max2 :Int? = amplitudes1.maxOrNull()
println(max2) //prints null
val max3:Int = amplitudes1.max() 
println(max3) // Throws NoSuchElementException
```

[Playground Link](https://pl.kotl.in/LaOJcXCvz)